# Multiple file chunks transfer over socket to multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets

I have to transfer chunks of a file to different clients using one server.
When i run the server file and provide the name of the file it successfully makes chunks. when i run the first client for first time it works but when i run it for the client again(by that i mean when i connect as a second client) it fails to transfer chunks to the second client. Complete code of server and client are shown below.
error is for the second client it starts reading the contents of the file as filename and program terminates.
provide a large text file(1MB) file as input to server

Server Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class server {

    private static final int sPort = 8000;   //The server will be listening on this port number
    public static String str;
    public static int c;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The server is running."); 
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(sPort);
        int clientNum = 1;
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = in.nextLine();
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String filepath = path +"/"+ str;
        in.close();
        try {
            c=splitFile(new File(filepath));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            try {
                    while(true) {
                        new Handler(listener.accept(),clientNum,c).start();
                System.out.println("Client "  + clientNum + " is connected!");
                clientNum++;
                        }
            } finally {
                    listener.close();
            } 

        }

    /**
        * A handler thread class.  Handlers are spawned from the listening
        * loop and are responsible for dealing with a single client's requests.
        */
        private static class Handler extends Thread {

        private Socket connection;
        private int chunkcount;
            private ObjectInputStream in;   //stream read from the socket
            private ObjectOutputStream out;    //stream write to the socket
        private int no;     //The index number of the client

            public Handler(Socket connection, int no,int c) {
                this.connection = connection;
                this.no = no;
                this.chunkcount=c;
            }

        public void run() {
        try{
            //initialize Input and Output streams
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            try{
                String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                path=path+"/"+"chunks"+ "/";

                System.out.println(path);

                System.out.println("Total chunks: "+chunkcount);

                int i=no;
                int j=i;
                int k=0;
                 OutputStream op=connection.getOutputStream();
                 DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(op);

                 d.writeInt(no);
                 d.flush();
                 System.out.println("value of j or clientnum: "+j);
                 while(j<chunkcount)
                 {
                     k++;
                     j=j+5;
                 }

                 System.out.println(k);
                 d.writeInt(k);
                 d.flush();
                 //d.close();

                 while(i<chunkcount)
                    {
                         String pathname= path+Integer.toString(i)+str;
                         System.out.println(i+str);

                         sendFile(connection,pathname);
                         i=i+5;

                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            System.out.println("Disconnect with Client " + no);
        }
        finally{
            //Close connections
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                connection.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                System.out.println("Disconnect with Client " + no);
            }
        }
    }

        }       

        public static int splitFile(File f) throws IOException {
            int partCounter = 1;//I like to name parts from 001, 002, 003, ...
                                //you can change it to 0 if you want 000, 001, ...

            int sizeOfFiles = 102400;// 1MB
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

            try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(f))) {//try-with-resources to ensure closing stream
                String name = f.getName();
                String path = f.getParent();
                long sizefile = f.getTotalSpace();
                String newpath = path + "/" + "chunks";
                File dir = new File(newpath);
                dir.mkdir();

                int tmp = 0;
                while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    //write each chunk of data into separate file with different number in name
                    File newFile = new File(dir, String.format("%d", partCounter++) + name );
                    //System.out.println(f.getParent());
                    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, tmp);//tmp is chunk size
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("File details are : "+name+"  "+sizefile);
                System.out.println("Number of chunks: "+ (partCounter-1));
            }
            return (partCounter-1);
        }



         public static void sendFile(Socket conn,String fileName) throws IOException
            {

                 File myFile = new File(fileName);
                 byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                 dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

                 OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

                 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

                 dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
                 dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
                 dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                 dos.flush();
                 dis.close();

            }

}
```

client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;



public class Client {
    Socket requestSocket;           //socket connect to the server
    ObjectOutputStream out;         //stream write to the socket
    ObjectInputStream in;          //stream read from the socket


    public Client() {}


    void run()
    {

        try{
            //create a socket to connect to the server
            requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
            System.out.println("Connected to localhost in port 8000");
            //initialize inputStream and outputStream
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());





             System.out.println("Ready to receive files ( Enter QUIT to end):");



            BufferedInputStream in1 = new BufferedInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
            DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in1);

            int clientnum=d.readInt();
             String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String oppath = path + "/" + "Client" + clientnum;
            File dir = new File(oppath);
            dir.mkdir();


            int numchunk=d.readInt();
            System.out.println(numchunk);
            int jakarta=1;
            while(jakarta<=numchunk ){
                    jakarta++;



                    String newpath=oppath+"/";
                    File f = new File(newpath);
                    f.createNewFile();


                   receiveFile(requestSocket,newpath);
                    System.out.println("File Received");
            }

        }
        catch (ConnectException e) {
                System.err.println("Connection refused. You need to initiate a server first.");
        } 

        catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost){
            System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //Close connections
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                requestSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //send a message to the output stream
    public static void receiveFile(Socket s1,String oppath) throws IOException
    {
        String fileName;

        try {
            int bytesRead;
            InputStream in = s1.getInputStream();

            DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);

            fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(oppath+fileName);
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0
                    && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                            (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    //main method
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: 'It fails to transfer' is not a problem description. Why are you creating object streams and not using them? And why the chunking?

Comment: The program contains more logic than it is in description. What should client do? Should it transfer one chunk only and if yes what does the magic variable `jakarta` mean? And what does mean the obfuscation with the constant `5` in server?